# Would a reverse proxy such as NGINX work to have my domain route to content on different servers (Kajabi and Vercel)?

Tags: next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, vercel, supabase, kajabi

Initial conditions: We have a highly converting site with multiple products on Kajabi.

Problem: I have created a subscription service on Vercel (Next.js) that we wish to deploy on the same domain that currently routes to Kajabi.

End State: Achieve greatest SEO performance by having the same domain name route to different servers.

Our domain is pointed at Kajabi, where we have thousands of nested pages with multiple content creators using Kajabi's WYSIWYG builder.

I have built a site in Next.js that is deployed on Vercel.

How can I have mydomain.com route to the appropriate server?

[image: The Situation]

Would a reverse proxy, such as NGINX, work in this instance?[image: NGINX - Reverse Proxy]

Stack: Supabase/Next.js/Vercel/Stripe

Comment: It's doable, but you must pay attention to the possible cons https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/5769